# SVM on top of an autoencoder for image classification: 100% accuracy on train and test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, autoencoder

I have a **small** image data set with 4 classes. So I've used an auto-encoder to extract features automatically.

These features are fed to an Support Vector Machine classifier in order to do the classification task.

After training the auto encoder for 10 epochs and training the SVM model on the extracted features I've  got these confusion matrices:[image: accuracy on the training data]

[image: accuracy on the test data]

My concern is about if the model isn't as general as possible in order to be applicable on a new data.

***My question is:* Is  there any method to know if the model is over fitting except testing it on some other samples?**

EDIT:
This is the code for the auto encoder:

```
encoder_input = Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3), name='original_img')
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3))(encoder_input)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu')(x)
encoder_output = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoder_output, name='encoder')
encoder.summary()

decoder_input = Input(shape=(32, 35, 64,), name='encoded_img')
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu')   (decoder_input)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoder_output  = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, padding='same',   activation='relu')(x)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
autoencoder_input = Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3), name='img')
encoded_img = encoder(autoencoder_input)
decoded_img = decoder(encoded_img)
Autoencoder = Model(autoencoder_input, decoded_img, name='autoencoder')
Autoencoder.summary()

total_train = 80
total_val = 40
Autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

history = Autoencoder.fit_generator(
train_data_gen,
steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=val_data_gen,
validation_steps=total_val // batch_size
```

)

The code for the SVM and confusion matrices:

```
samples, y = next(train_data_gen_svm)
samples_val, y_val = next(val_data_gen_svm)

#Get features
X = encoder.predict(samples)
X_val = encoder.predict(samples_val)

# Reshape for the SVM input
X_reshape = X.reshape(80,32*35*64)
X_val_reshape = X_val.reshape(40,32*35*64)

clf = SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3)

print('X shape:', X_reshape.shape)
print('y shape: ', X_val_reshape.shape)

clf.fit(X_reshape, y)

y_pred_val = clf.predict(X_val_reshape)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_reshape)

cnf_matrix_val = confusion_matrix(y_val, y_pred_val,normalize='true')
cnf_matrix_train = confusion_matrix(y,y_pred_train,normalize='true')
```

Comment: Simple answer: no. But that of course doesn't mean that there has not been some kind of leakage in your data, which no one can know without your code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I've included the code in the question.

Comment: How `val_data_gen_svm` is created? Also, what are the images? Is it "obvious" to tell apart different classes?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski  The images are from a radar, they are not obvious to discern.  the code to 'val_data_gen_svm' is:  ```val_data_gen_svm = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=40,
                                                              directory=validation_dir,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='sparse')```

Comment: can you check for a copy/paste error in the folder used by the generators ? Is it possible they use the same folder ?

Comment: @CoMartel, I checked the paths of the two generators.They are not the same.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that your model is that successful. As @CoMartel said, I'd look for coding errors and check carefully each line with debugger. Also, would be great if you could paste how confusion matrix looks like without normalisation. No need for pretty pictures. Last but not least, you can always set aside small portion of images from each class and run them separately through the pipeline. Check if results match.

Comment: okay. Can you reduce your training set & increase the size of your testing set ? (Invert them is an easy way to start). If your implementation is correct, you should notice a difference in your confusion matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check again if there are any errors in the code and share if I find any error.

Comment: @CoMartel I tried what you said. I switched some classes to see any difference in the confusion matrix, apparently everything is OK. I've got 100% of missclassified images in both classes (Each class has 10 samples ).                                                                                                       [[10  0  0  0]  
 [ 0  0 10  0]  
 [ 0 10  0  0]  
 [ 0  0  0 10]]                                                                                    I tested the model on an external data, it seems that its working perfectly.However, I'm still feeling suspicious about this.

Comment: You have several possibilities : your implementation is wrong on some level, your task is easy to classify or you have a leak in your images. You should extract the encoded features to check if something's odd (vectors too similar for different images). One way to check for data generator issues is to mislabel some images on purpose on the training set : if your implementation is correct, you should expect more errors in your training score and your testing score